# how to reduce the native font size of a windows cordova app?

Tags: windows, cordova

I have a windows Cordova app and I want to reduce the font size of its native elements (for eg, the drop-down list)
I found out that the font size is being set from a theme file which is not editable. can I override the font size?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova renders the content of your app in the Windows WebView control which is the only native control that it renders. So everything inside your Cordova app is essentially a web app running in the WebView control. This means that you could reduce the font size of the drop-down list by adjusting the CSS class associated with the drop-down list or in general the CSS for the body element.

E.g. In your CSS file:

```
body { font-size: 80%; }
```

Comment: the drop down menu is the native one and the font adjustments we make within the app is not having any affect on it.the list is getting cut and the font size is too big for the phone.